# PHPMailer apresentando uma mensagem desconhecida

Tags: php, phpmailer

O meu código está funcionando porém quando é executado, junto da mensagem (que aparece ao concluir o processo de envio), aparece as seguintes informações:

```
2014-11-18 16:19:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO .org.br 
2014-11-18 16:19:05 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 
2014-11-18 16:19:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO .org.br 
2014-11-18 16:19:06 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2014-11-18 16:19:06 CLIENT -> SERVER:  
2014-11-18 16:19:06 CLIENT -> SERVER:  
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 14:19:05 -0200 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: To:  
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Portal AMB 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <55a2e47f191a@.org.br> 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.9 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: Conforme o solicitado, segue abaixo o link para a mudança de sua senha: Clique aqui visite este link para recuperar a sua senha: 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: 
2014-11-18 16:19:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: . 
2014-11-18 16:19:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT parabéns!
```

Eu não queria que aparecesse isso, como não sou experiente em PHP não tenho noção da onde ele está gerando essa mensagem, será que alguém que conheça o PHPMailer sabe o que é essa mensagem de server?

A mensagem apresenta todas as informações do meu server junto das informações que são enviadas para a pessoa, ai eu tirei para perguntar a vocês.

O servidor que utilizo é Windows.

Comment: Posta o código que envia o email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chave para a questão estava na configuração:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

esse `SMTPDebug` estava com o valor boleano "1" ou seja, ativo... ele estava mostrando todo o processo do envio.